# M1 VS Code Live Server extension dont launch chrome

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, apple-m1, liveserver

I have setup Vscode on a new m1 macbook, but Live server extension doesn't seem to work. Specifically is not launching the browser (Chrome).  This is my setting.json file document :

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome",
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "liveServer.settings.useBrowserPreview": false ,

    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay", 
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It happens to me too. THere's an updated extension (Live Server is no longer maintained), which is calle Five Server. But it doesn't launch the browser (as it should) either, at least in my case with a Macbook M1 also

Answer (score 0):

Opening wthe very folder where the index.html is located directly in VsCode (as opposed to some of the ascendant (parent of parent of...) folder, makes Five Server work for me - it is now able to open the Chrome browser and update it automatically.

Maybe is the same for Live Server, but again Five Server is an updated fork of Live Server -Live Server is no longer maintained

[image: Open Folder Menu (you might need to select a folder in VSCode for the OpenFolder not to be greyed out)]

Comment: And you have to name the html file "index.html". It doesn't work for me if not (and probably you'll have to name the .css file "style.css" but haven't tested that

Answer (score 0):

Try to write this in `setting.json`

```
"liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "Google Chrome.app"
```

instead

```
"liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome"
```